# Add custom words to Video Studio Intellisense 2008 C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0, intellisense

its possible to add my own strings to visual studio 2008 intellisense for C# using only xsd file? (without class library and without any implemented methods.)

for example I will edit here an scenario:
xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://SampleCustomer" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Customers">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Customer">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Address" />             
            </xs:sequence>           
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

code behind (using VS 2008 C#): when I will press ctrl+shift it will open intellisense and I want to use/select from intellisense Customer.
Is there a way to solve it? if yes, how can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this in Visual Studio 2008, but I have with Visual Studio 2005 and *Option 1* from the instructions works well.

> Copy the XSD into the Visual Studio 2005 schemas directory
>
> Place a copy of the XSD file into the
>   folder %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 8\XML\Schemas

For 2008, use the directory

> %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9\XML\Schemas

http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2005/12/07/501466.aspx

Comment: thanks for ur reply but.. I tried it today for few times and doesnt work in code behind. I can call my Customer and his properties like tags in app and web config files. but nothing is workin` in c#.